# Dependency Injection: What should be injected where?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I have a number of classes that contain the ability to be written to either a CSV or XML file.
To accomplish this, I pass in an instance of a StreamWriter or XmlWriter to ToCsv or ToXml methods.

```
public class HandFeed : JobItem
{
    // Snip

    public override void ToCsv(StreamWriter writer)
    {
        if (writer != null)
        {
            writer.WriteLine(JobItemsStrings.Job_HandFeed);
            writer.WriteLine(JobItemsStrings.Job_Total + SEPARATOR_CHAR + this.Total.ToString());
        }
    }

    public override void ToXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        if (writer != null)
        {
            writer.WriteStartElement("handfeed");
            writer.WriteElementString("total", this.Total.ToString());
            writer.WriteEndElement();
        }
    }
}
```

Now I am looking to provide suport for JSON too, and if I carry on in the same way, this would mean adding another method to all my classes along the lines of 'ToJson' or similar.

Well, this feels like it is wrong somehow. I am thinking of maybe doing things the other way around and passing instances of the classes to different file writer objects instead, but not really sure if this would be the right thing to do either, or even how best to accomplish it.

Perhaps I can pass in an interface and call `Write()`? This *feels* like it would be more correct, but again, how to put this into practice.

So, my questions in a nutshell are:

- Should the classes be 'injected' with writers?
- Should some writers be 'injected' with the classes?
- Stick with the current setup, but create some form of interface instead?

Any advice welcome.

Comment: I'm thinking the Visitor design pattern could be useful here. Each writer would have it's own class derived from the Visitor base class.

Comment: Could you provide some examples of how your code typically uses these serialization methods?

Comment: @alun : foreach(JobItem item in jobItemsList) item.ToCsv(writer);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write "Writers" that conform to an interface and inject the writers. However this would mean that a given object can only be written to a single format in any single state. This might not be a problem for you, and if it isn't this is a practical approach.

The other option would be to create writers that conform to the interface but leave the objects out of the business of writing themselves out. Instead some caller can setup the writer and pass the object to it. This relates to a question I just answered:

[Should classes be able to save and load themselves via XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6917106/should-classes-be-able-to-save-and-load-themselves-via-xml)

In your case the caller that wishes to write out then can get the "writer" via some factory that is able to resolve the correct writer to use.

I wouldn't stick to your current setup because as you mention, each time a new format is needed, you need to modify your existing code and add methods for that format. Also, you are telling your objects that they should know how to do too much.

Comment: The single format in a single state would not be a problem, but I am interested in your 2nd point. You are suggesting making the class a dependency of a writer, and lose the ToCsv, ToXml methods altogether. Do I understand you correctly?

Comment: Kinda. You do want to lose the ToCsv, ToXml methods from your JobItem. In place you have a bunch of writers (one per format) that conform to say the "IWrite" interface. In the places where you are calling .ToCsv today then instead you call writer.Write(jobItem) or something similar. The writer instance can be discovered/retrieved via some factory that knows the current format being used (configured upon process entry for example).

Comment: OK, I think I get that. The next problem would be how to decide what data to actually write. The above class is a simple one, and there are others that vary in complexity, number of properties, name of properties etc.

Comment: One way to do that is to annotate your class. Just like when doing Xml serialization in .Net where you can specify what to ignore and what to write. You can generalize that concept so that your writers can look at attributes of properties and decide whether or not to write them out. You can excuse this from single responsibility by saying that the item in this case is simply saying what of itself is publishable. Who and how it gets published the item doesn't care. You can come up with your own set of attributes that fits what you need.

Comment: Thanks a lot, given me plenty to think about. I'll accept your answer as I feel it has given me a good idea of what to do, and a path to follow. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to apply the servant design pattern, you can read about it on this [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_pattern_Servant)